# commands to find Avg, Max, Min in DF

Tags: r

I need to show the unique Count by Url and then show the Avg, Max, Min time that it took as different columns. Was looking at using either dplyr or sqldf.
here is what I am essentially trying to duplicate

```
SELECT cs-uri-stem as Url, COUNT(*) as totalRequests, 
AVG(time-taken) As avgRequestDuration, 
MAX(time-taken) As maxRequestDuration, 
MIN(time-taken) As minRequestDuration 
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
GROUP BY Url
ORDER By totalRequests DESC
```

Head of data for reference:

```
> head(iislog1)
     iisdate  iistime                                              csUriStem timeTaken
1 2019-05-17 03:05:39 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding      7421
2 2019-05-17 03:07:22          /Services/2015V1/EngService.svc/customBinding      8390
3 2019-05-17 03:16:40 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding       515
4 2019-05-17 03:17:39 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding       505
5 2019-05-17 03:25:22          /Services/2015V1/EngService.svc/customBinding      1385
6 2019-05-17 03:31:16    /eAudIT/Services/SAPv1/EngService.svc/customBinding      1365
```

structure(list(iisdate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2019-05-17", class = "factor"), 
    iistime = structure(1:6, .Label = c("03:05:39", "03:07:22", 
    "03:16:40", "03:17:39", "03:25:22", "03:31:16", "03:44:02", 
    "04:27:09", "04:27:11", "04:27:19", "04:27:20", "04:27:22", 
    "04:27:30", "04:27:33", "04:27:36", "04:27:40", "04:27:42", 
    "04:27:43", "04:27:44", "04:27:45", "04:27:46", "04:27:47", 
    "04:27:48", "04:27:50", "04:27:51", "04:27:55", "04:27:57", 
    "04:28:00", "04:28:01", "04:28:02", "04:28:03", "04:28:05", 
    "04:28:06", "04:28:08", "04:28:10", "04:28:19", "04:28:26", 
    "04:28:27", "04:28:28", "04:28:29", "04:28:32", "04:28:37", 
    "04:28:50", "04:28:51", "04:28:53", "04:28:54", "04:28:55", 
    "04:28:56", "04:28:57", "04:29:00", "04:29:16", "04:29:18", 
    "04:29:19", "04:29:20", "04:29:21", "04:29:23", "04:29:24", 
    "04:29:25", "04:29:26", "04:29:29", "04:29:30", "04:29:33", 
    "04:29:35", "04:29:37", "04:29:38", "04:30:27", "04:30:29", 
    "04:30:31", "04:30:32", "04:30:40", "04:30:43", "04:30:58", 
    "04:31:00", "04:31:01", "04:31:02", "04:31:04", "04:31:08", 
    "04:31:46", "04:31:47", "04:31:48", "04:31:49", "04:31:54", 
    "04:31:55", "04:31:56", "04:31:58", "04:31:59", "04:32:01", 
    "04:32:02", "04:32:03", "04:32:04", "04:32:05", "04:32:06", 
    "04:32:08", "04:32:09", "04:32:11", "04:32:12", "04:32:14", 
    "04:32:15", "04:32:17", "04:32:20", "04:32:27", "04:32:39", 
    "04:32:41", "04:32:42", "04:32:45", "04:32:58", "04:33:03", 
    "04:33:04", "04:33:08", "04:33:10", "04:33:11", "04:33:12", 
    "04:33:14", "04:33:15", "04:33:17", "04:33:18", "04:33:41", 
    "04:33:42", "04:33:44", "04:33:49", "04:33:50", "04:33:51", 
    "04:33:52", "04:33:53", "04:33:55", "04:33:57", "04:33:58", 
    "04:34:00", "04:34:02", "04:34:04", "04:34:05", "04:34:07", 
    "04:34:08", "04:34:10", "04:34:12", "04:34:15", "04:34:16", 
    "04:34:18", "04:34:25", "04:34:28", "04:34:39", "04:34:40", 
    "04:34:42", "04:34:43", "04:34:46", "04:34:51", "04:34:57", 
    "04:34:58", "04:35:01", "04:35:02", "04:35:10", "04:35:13", 
    "04:35:14", "04:35:15", "04:35:16", "04:35:17", "04:35:19", 
    "04:35:20", "04:35:21", "04:35:22", "04:35:24", "04:35:25", 
    "04:35:27", "04:35:29", "04:35:30", "04:35:31", "04:35:34", 
    "04:35:35", "04:35:38", "04:35:40", "04:35:49", "04:36:01", 
    "04:36:02", "04:36:05", "04:36:26", "04:36:28", "04:36:29", 
    "04:36:31", "04:36:32", "04:36:33", "04:36:36", "04:36:41", 
    "04:36:42", "04:36:43", "04:36:44", "04:36:45", "04:36:47", 
    "04:36:49", "04:36:51", "04:36:53", "04:36:54", "04:36:55", 
    "04:36:56", "04:36:57", "04:36:58", "04:37:00", "04:37:01", 
    "04:37:02", "04:37:04", "04:37:07", "04:37:11", "04:37:16", 
    "04:37:29", "04:37:30", "04:37:31", "04:37:33", "04:37:35", 
    "04:38:08", "04:38:09", "04:38:17", "04:38:18", "04:38:19", 
    "04:38:23", "04:38:24", "04:38:25", "04:38:27", "04:38:28", 
    "04:38:29", "04:38:30", "04:38:31", "04:38:32", "04:38:34", 
    "04:38:35", "04:38:36", "04:38:41", "04:38:42", "04:38:43", 
    "04:39:14", "04:39:15", "04:39:16", "04:39:17", "04:39:19", 
    "04:39:30", "04:39:31", "04:39:44", "04:39:45", "04:39:46", 
    "04:39:48", "04:39:50", "04:40:00", "04:40:01", "04:40:03", 
    "04:40:06", "04:40:07", "04:40:08", "04:40:09", "04:40:11", 
    "04:40:12", "04:40:13", "04:40:14", "04:40:16", "04:40:19", 
    "04:40:20", "04:40:22", "04:40:24", "05:00:45", "05:07:01", 
    "05:07:03", "05:07:05", "05:07:35", "05:07:36", "05:07:38", 
    "05:07:39", "05:07:42", "05:07:44", "05:07:45", "05:07:46", 
    "05:07:49", "05:08:04", "05:08:05", "05:08:06", "05:08:07", 
    "05:08:08", "05:08:09", "05:08:10", "05:08:11", "05:08:24", 
    "05:08:30", "05:08:31", "05:08:37", "05:08:38", "05:08:39", 
    "05:08:40", "05:08:52", "05:08:58", "05:08:59", "05:09:02", 
    "05:09:03", "05:11:50", "05:11:52", "05:11:53", "05:11:59", 
    "05:12:00", "05:12:01", "05:12:02", "05:12:03", "05:12:04", 
    "05:12:06", "05:12:07", "05:12:08", "05:12:09", "05:12:10", 
    "05:12:11", "05:13:46", "05:13:47", "05:13:48", "05:13:50", 
    "05:13:51", "05:13:53", "05:13:55", "05:13:56", "05:13:59", 
    "05:14:05", "05:14:07", "05:14:08", "05:14:10", "05:14:11", 
    "05:14:12", "05:14:14", "05:14:16", "05:14:18", "05:14:19", 
    "05:14:20", "05:14:21", "05:14:22", "05:14:24", "05:14:25", 
    "05:14:27", "05:14:28", "05:14:29", "05:14:30", "05:14:31", 
    "05:14:32", "05:14:33", "05:14:34", "05:14:36", "05:14:37", 
    "05:14:38", "05:14:39", "05:14:40", "05:14:41", "05:14:42", 
    "05:14:43", "05:14:44", "05:14:45", "05:14:46", "05:14:47", 
    "05:14:48", "05:14:50", "05:14:51", "05:14:52", "05:14:54", 
    "05:14:55", "05:14:56", "05:14:57", "05:14:58", "05:14:59", 
    "05:15:00", "05:15:01", "05:15:02", "05:15:03", "05:15:04", 
    "05:15:06", "05:15:07", "05:15:08", "05:15:09", "05:15:10", 
    "05:15:11", "05:15:12", "05:15:13", "05:15:15", "05:15:16", 
    "05:15:17", "05:15:18", "05:15:19", "05:15:20", "05:15:21", 
    "05:15:22", "05:15:24", "05:15:25", "05:15:26", "05:15:27", 
    "05:15:28", "05:15:29", "05:15:31", "05:15:32", "05:15:33", 
    "05:15:34", "05:15:35", "05:15:36", "05:15:37", "05:15:38", 
    "05:15:39", "05:15:40", "05:15:41", "05:15:42", "05:15:43", 
    "05:15:44", "05:15:45", "05:15:46", "05:15:48", "05:15:49", 
    "05:15:50", "05:15:51", "05:15:52", "05:15:53", "05:15:54", 
    "05:15:55", "05:15:56", "05:15:57", "05:15:58", "05:15:59", 
    "05:16:00", "05:16:01", "05:16:03", "05:16:04", "05:16:05", 
    "05:16:06", "05:16:07", "05:16:09", "05:16:10", "05:16:11", 
    "05:16:12", "05:16:13", "05:16:14", "05:16:15", "05:16:17", 
    "05:16:19", "05:16:21", "05:16:22", "05:16:23", "05:16:24", 
    "05:16:25", "05:16:26", "05:16:28", "05:16:29", "05:16:30", 
    "05:16:31", "05:16:32", "05:16:34", "05:16:35", "05:16:36", 
    "05:16:37", "05:16:38", "05:16:39", "05:16:41", "05:16:42", 
    "05:16:43", "05:16:44", "05:16:45", "05:16:47", "05:16:54", 
    "05:17:13", "05:17:14", "05:17:15", "05:17:16", "05:17:18", 
    "05:17:19", "05:17:20", "05:17:21", "05:17:22", "05:17:23", 
    "05:17:25", "05:21:37", "05:21:39", "05:21:40", "05:21:42", 
    "05:21:44", "05:21:48", "05:21:54", "05:21:55", "05:21:57", 
    "05:21:58", "05:21:59", "05:22:00", "05:22:01", "05:22:02", 
    "05:22:03", "05:22:05", "05:22:06", "05:22:07", "05:22:08", 
    "05:22:09", "05:22:10", "05:22:11", "05:22:12", "05:22:14", 
    "05:22:15", "05:22:18", "05:22:21", "05:31:23", "05:31:24", 
    "05:31:26", "05:31:27", "05:31:28", "05:31:29", "05:31:31", 
    "05:31:34", "05:31:39", "05:31:57", "05:31:58", "05:31:59", 
    "05:32:01", "05:32:02", "05:32:03", "05:38:29", "05:38:32", 
    "05:39:08", "05:39:09", "05:39:10", "05:39:11", "05:39:12", 
    "05:39:14", "05:39:15", "05:39:28", "05:41:58", "05:42:00", 
    "05:42:02", "05:42:05", "05:42:07", "05:42:08", "05:42:09", 
    "05:42:11", "05:42:12", "05:42:13", "05:52:15", "05:52:16", 
    "05:52:17", "05:52:18", "05:52:20", "05:52:24", "05:52:26", 
    "05:52:53", "05:53:06", "05:53:08", "05:53:09", "05:55:21", 
    "05:55:23", "05:55:24", "05:55:25", "05:55:27", "05:55:28", 
    "05:55:29", "05:55:30", "05:55:31", "05:55:33", "06:17:42", 
    "06:17:44", "06:17:49", "06:18:03", "06:18:04", "06:18:06", 
    "06:18:08", "06:18:10", "06:18:11", "06:18:13", "06:18:14", 
    "06:18:15", "06:18:18", "06:18:19", "06:18:21", "06:18:22", 
    "06:18:23", "06:18:24", "06:18:25", "06:18:26", "06:18:28", 
    "06:18:30", "06:18:31", "06:18:33", "06:18:35", "06:18:43", 
    "06:18:44", "06:18:46", "06:18:48", "06:18:49", "06:18:51", 
    "06:18:53", "06:18:54", "06:18:55", "06:18:58", "06:19:00", 
    "06:19:02", "06:19:03", "06:19:04", "06:19:09", "06:19:14", 
    "06:19:15", "06:19:16", "06:19:18", "06:19:19", "06:19:20", 
    "06:19:22", "06:19:23", "06:19:25", "06:19:26", "06:19:28", 
    "06:19:30", "06:19:31", "06:19:32", "06:19:44", "06:19:48", 
    "06:19:49", "06:19:50", "06:19:51", "06:19:53", "06:19:54", 
    "06:19:56", "06:19:57", "06:19:58", "06:20:00", "06:20:01", 
    "06:20:05", "06:20:06", "06:21:02", "06:21:04", "06:21:05", 
    "06:21:08", "06:21:12", "06:21:29", "06:21:30", "06:21:32", 
    "06:22:05", "06:22:06", "06:24:45", "06:24:47", "06:24:51", 
    "06:24:53", "06:24:56", "06:24:57", "06:24:58", "06:25:00", 
    "06:25:02", "06:25:03", "06:25:04", "06:25:05", "06:25:06", 
    "06:25:10", "06:25:13", "06:25:15", "06:25:16", "06:25:18", 
    "06:25:19", "06:25:23", "06:25:27", "06:25:38", "06:25:39", 
    "06:25:41", "06:27:16", "06:27:17", "06:31:27", "06:31:28", 
    "06:31:29", "06:31:30", "06:31:32", "06:31:33", "06:31:34", 
    "06:31:35", "06:31:37", "06:31:38", "06:31:39", "06:31:40", 
    "06:31:41", "06:31:42", "06:31:43", "06:31:44", "06:31:45", 
    "06:31:47", "06:31:48", "06:31:49", "06:31:50", "06:31:51", 
    "06:31:52", "06:31:53", "06:31:54", "06:31:55", "06:31:57", 
    "06:31:58", "06:31:59", "06:32:00", "06:32:01", "06:32:02", 
    "06:32:03", "06:32:04", "06:32:05", "06:32:06", "06:32:08", 
    "06:32:09", "06:32:10", "06:32:11", "06:32:12", "06:32:13", 
    "06:32:15", "06:37:17", "06:37:19", "06:37:20", "06:37:22", 
    "06:37:23", "06:37:24", "06:37:26", "06:37:27", "06:37:28", 
    "06:37:29", "06:37:41", "06:37:42", "06:37:47", "06:37:49", 
    "06:37:50", "06:37:51", "06:37:52", "06:37:53", "06:37:58", 
    "06:37:59", "06:40:11", "06:40:13", "06:40:14", "06:40:15", 
    "06:40:16", "06:40:18", "06:40:19", "06:40:20", "06:40:21", 
    "06:40:22", "06:40:23", "06:40:24", "06:40:25", "06:40:26", 
    "06:40:50", "06:40:51", "06:40:52", "06:40:53", "06:40:54", 
    "06:40:56", "06:40:57", "06:40:59", "06:41:01", "06:41:04", 
    "06:41:17", "06:41:18", "06:41:40", "06:42:43", "06:42:45", 
    "06:48:50", "06:48:51", "06:49:10", "06:49:12", "06:49:14", 
    "06:50:21", "06:50:22", "06:50:31", "06:50:32", "06:50:33", 
    "06:50:44", "06:50:45", "06:52:37", "06:52:38", "06:52:39", 
    "06:56:39", "06:56:41", "06:56:43", "06:59:16", "06:59:18", 
    "06:59:19", "06:59:22", "06:59:23", "06:59:24", "06:59:25", 
    "06:59:27", "06:59:28", "06:59:29", "06:59:30", "07:02:50", 
    "07:02:52", "07:02:54", "07:02:55", "07:02:56", "07:02:58", 
    "07:02:59", "07:03:00", "07:06:52", "07:06:54", "07:06:56", 
    "07:06:57", "07:06:58", "07:07:00", "07:07:02", "07:07:04", 
    "07:07:05", "07:07:06", "07:07:07", "07:09:38", "07:09:39", 
    "07:35:15", "07:35:18", "07:35:20", "07:35:23", "07:35:25", 
    "07:35:26", "07:35:27", "07:35:28", "07:35:29", "07:35:30", 
    "07:35:32", "07:35:33", "07:35:35", "07:35:36", "07:35:37", 
    "07:35:38", "07:35:39", "07:35:40", "07:35:41", "07:36:44", 
    "07:37:09", "07:37:33", "07:37:58", "07:38:23", "07:46:13", 
    "08:33:43", "08:33:47", "08:33:50", "08:33:58", "08:34:01", 
    "08:34:02", "08:34:04", "08:34:05", "08:34:06", "08:34:07", 
    "08:34:09", "08:34:14", "08:34:15", "08:34:28", "08:34:30", 
    "08:34:31", "08:34:32", "08:34:33", "08:34:34", "08:34:36", 
    "08:34:37", "08:34:38", "08:34:39", "08:34:40", "08:34:47", 
    "08:34:49", "08:34:55", "08:34:56", "08:34:57", "08:34:58", 
    "08:34:59", "08:35:00", "08:35:05", "08:35:06", "08:35:08", 
    "08:35:11", "08:35:12", "08:35:13", "08:35:15", "08:35:17", 
    "08:35:18", "08:35:20", "08:35:21", "08:35:23", "08:35:25", 
    "08:35:37", "08:35:38", "08:35:39", "08:35:40", "08:35:41", 
    "08:35:42", "08:35:43", "08:59:09", "08:59:12", "08:59:13", 
    "08:59:15", "09:00:56", "09:00:57", "09:00:59", "09:01:00", 
    "09:01:02", "09:01:21", "09:22:31", "09:22:34", "09:22:51", 
    "09:22:53", "09:22:54", "09:22:55", "09:22:57", "09:22:58", 
    "09:22:59", "09:23:00", "09:23:01", "09:23:02", "09:23:03", 
    "09:23:04", "09:23:05", "09:23:06", "09:23:07", "09:23:08", 
    "09:23:10", "09:23:11", "09:23:12", "09:23:16", "09:23:17", 
    "09:23:18", "09:23:19", "09:23:24", "09:23:26", "09:23:29", 
    "09:23:30", "09:23:31", "09:23:32", "09:23:33", "09:23:36", 
    "09:23:37", "09:23:38", "09:23:43", "09:23:45", "09:23:46", 
    "09:23:48", "09:23:49", "09:23:50", "09:23:51", "09:23:52", 
    "09:23:53", "09:23:55", "09:23:56", "09:23:57", "09:23:58", 
    "09:24:01", "09:24:03", "09:24:04", "09:24:06", "09:24:07", 
    "09:24:10", "09:24:11", "09:24:13", "09:24:14", "09:24:15", 
    "09:24:16", "09:24:17", "09:24:18", "09:24:19", "09:24:20", 
    "09:24:21", "09:24:23", "09:24:24", "09:24:25", "09:24:26", 
    "09:24:27", "09:24:29", "09:24:30", "09:24:31", "09:24:32", 
    "09:24:33", "09:24:34", "09:24:35", "09:24:37", "09:24:38", 
    "09:24:39", "09:24:40", "09:24:41", "09:24:42", "09:24:43", 
    "09:24:44", "09:24:45", "09:24:46", "09:24:48", "09:24:49", 
    "09:24:50", "09:24:51", "09:24:52", "09:24:53", "09:24:55", 
    "09:24:56", "09:24:57", "09:24:58", "09:25:00", "09:25:01", 
    "09:25:02", "09:25:03", "09:25:04", "09:25:06", "09:25:07", 
    "09:25:08", "09:25:09", "09:25:10", "09:25:12", "09:25:13", 
    "09:25:14", "09:25:15", "09:25:16", "09:25:17", "09:25:18", 
    "09:25:19", "09:25:29", "09:25:32", "09:25:34", "09:25:45", 
    "09:25:47", "09:25:48", "09:25:50", "09:25:52", "09:25:53", 
    "09:25:55", "09:25:56", "09:26:01", "09:26:14", "09:26:16", 
    "09:26:17", "09:26:19", "09:26:21", "09:26:22", "09:26:24", 
    "09:26:25", "09:26:26", "09:26:29", "09:26:30", "09:26:35", 
    "09:26:36", "09:26:37", "09:26:39", "09:26:42", "09:26:45", 
    "09:26:47", "09:26:48", "09:26:53", "09:26:55", "09:26:57", 
    "09:26:58", "09:26:59", "09:27:01", "09:27:04", "09:27:06", 
    "09:27:09", "09:27:12", "09:27:13", "09:27:14", "09:27:16", 
    "09:27:17", "09:27:18", "09:27:19", "09:27:20", "09:27:21", 
    "09:27:23", "09:27:24", "09:27:25", "09:27:26", "09:27:27", 
    "09:27:28", "09:27:29", "09:27:30", "09:27:31", "09:27:32", 
    "09:27:33", "09:27:34", "09:27:35", "09:27:36", "09:27:37", 
    "09:27:39", "09:27:40", "09:27:41", "09:27:42", "09:27:43", 
    "09:27:44", "09:27:45", "09:27:46", "09:27:47", "09:27:48", 
    "09:27:49", "09:27:51", "09:27:52", "09:27:53", "09:27:54", 
    "09:27:55", "09:27:56", "09:27:57", "09:27:58", "09:28:00", 
    "09:28:01", "09:28:03", "09:28:04", "09:28:05", "09:28:07", 
    "09:28:08", "09:28:10", "09:28:16", "09:28:18", "09:28:21", 
    "09:28:22", "09:28:24", "09:28:25", "09:28:26", "09:28:27", 
    "09:28:28", "09:28:34", "09:28:35", "09:28:36", "09:28:37", 
    "09:28:38", "09:28:39", "09:28:41", "09:28:42", "09:28:44", 
    "09:28:45", "09:28:46", "09:28:47", "09:28:48", "09:28:49", 
    "09:28:50", "09:28:52", "09:28:53", "09:28:54", "09:28:55", 
    "09:28:56", "09:28:58", "09:29:01", "09:29:03", "09:29:04", 
    "09:29:06", "09:29:13", "09:29:29", "09:29:30", "09:29:33", 
    "09:29:34", "09:29:36", "09:30:25", "09:30:26", "09:30:29", 
    "09:30:30", "09:30:31", "09:30:36", "09:30:48", "09:30:50", 
    "09:31:45", "09:31:47", "09:31:50", "09:31:52", "09:31:54", 
    "09:31:55", "09:31:57", "09:31:59", "09:32:01", "10:00:52", 
    "10:00:55", "10:00:57", "10:00:59", "10:01:00", "10:01:01", 
    "10:01:03", "10:01:04", "10:01:05", "10:01:06", "10:01:07", 
    "10:01:08", "10:01:51", "10:01:52", "10:02:01", "10:02:02", 
    "10:02:03", "10:02:04", "10:02:05", "10:02:07", "10:02:17", 
    "10:02:22", "10:02:24", "10:02:25", "10:02:26", "10:02:27", 
    "10:02:28", "10:02:29", "10:02:31", "10:02:32", "10:02:38", 
    "10:02:39", "10:02:40", "10:02:42", "10:02:43", "10:02:58", 
    "10:03:00", "10:04:24", "10:04:27", "10:04:29", "10:04:31", 
    "10:04:32", "10:04:33", "10:04:35", "10:04:41", "10:04:42", 
    "10:04:43", "10:04:44", "10:04:45", "10:04:46", "10:04:47", 
    "10:04:48", "10:04:49", "10:04:50", "10:04:55", "10:05:03", 
    "10:05:05", "10:05:06", "10:05:07", "10:05:08", "10:05:09", 
    "10:05:10", "10:05:27", "10:05:29", "10:05:30", "10:05:31", 
    "10:05:32", "10:05:41", "10:05:43", "10:06:13", "10:06:14", 
    "10:06:15", "10:07:31", "10:07:32", "10:08:39", "10:08:41", 
    "10:08:52", "10:12:47", "10:12:49", "10:12:50", "10:12:52", 
    "10:12:54", "10:12:56", "10:12:58", "10:13:17", "10:13:18", 
    "10:13:19", "10:13:21", "10:13:23", "10:13:24", "10:13:25", 
    "10:13:26", "10:13:28", "10:13:29", "10:13:30", "10:13:33", 
    "10:13:36", "10:13:40", "10:13:41", "10:13:43", "10:13:44", 
    "10:13:46", "10:13:49", "10:13:58", "10:14:08", "10:14:09", 
    "10:14:11", "10:14:12", "10:14:14", "11:30:02", "11:30:03", 
    "11:30:04", "11:30:06", "11:30:08", "11:30:10", "11:30:12", 
    "11:30:15", "11:30:17", "11:30:18", "11:30:19", "11:30:23", 
    "11:30:24", "11:30:26", "11:30:27", "11:30:28", "11:30:29", 
    "11:30:31", "11:30:33", "11:30:35", "11:30:38", "11:30:39", 
    "11:30:42", "11:31:03", "11:31:04", "11:31:05", "11:31:22", 
    "11:31:27", "11:31:28", "11:31:31", "11:31:32", "11:31:34", 
    "11:31:36", "11:31:38", "11:32:09", "11:32:11", "11:32:13", 
    "11:32:15", "11:32:16", "11:32:18", "11:32:19", "11:32:20", 
    "11:32:22", "11:32:23", "11:32:24", "11:32:26", "11:32:28", 
    "11:32:31", "11:32:35", "11:32:36", "11:32:38", "11:32:51", 
    "11:32:53", "11:33:27", "11:33:34", "11:33:35", "11:33:36", 
    "11:33:37", "11:33:39", "11:33:43", "11:33:45", "11:33:46", 
    "11:33:48", "11:33:49", "11:33:51", "11:33:52", "11:33:53", 
    "11:33:55", "11:33:56", "11:33:59", "11:34:02", "11:34:03", 
    "11:34:04", "11:34:07", "11:34:08", "11:34:09", "11:34:19", 
    "11:34:37", "11:34:38", "11:34:49", "11:34:50", "11:34:55", 
    "11:34:56", "11:34:59", "11:35:00", "11:35:02", "11:35:05", 
    "11:35:06", "11:35:14", "11:35:28", "11:35:30", "11:35:43", 
    "11:35:45", "11:35:46", "11:35:47", "11:35:48", "11:35:50", 
    "11:35:56", "11:35:59", "11:36:01", "11:36:20", "11:36:21", 
    "11:36:23", "11:36:24", "11:36:25", "11:36:26", "11:36:27", 
    "11:36:50", "11:36:51", "11:36:58", "11:36:59", "11:37:00", 
    "11:37:01", "11:37:02", "11:37:03", "11:37:04", "11:37:05", 
    "11:37:16", "11:37:22", "11:37:23", "11:37:24", "11:37:26", 
    "11:37:27", "11:37:30", "11:37:31", "11:37:33", "11:37:35", 
    "11:37:37", "11:37:40", "11:37:42", "11:37:45", "11:37:51", 
    "11:37:53", "11:37:54", "11:37:56", "11:37:57", "11:37:59", 
    "11:38:02", "11:38:03", "11:38:05", "11:38:06", "11:38:07", 
    "11:38:08", "11:38:10", "11:38:11", "11:38:12", "11:38:13", 
    "11:38:14", "11:38:15", "11:38:16", "11:38:17", "11:38:18", 
    "11:38:19", "11:38:21", "11:38:22", "11:38:23", "11:38:24", 
    "11:38:25", "11:38:26", "11:38:27", "11:38:28", "11:38:30", 
    "11:38:31", "11:38:32", "11:38:33", "11:38:34", "11:38:35", 
    "11:38:36", "11:38:37", "11:38:38", "11:38:39", "11:38:41", 
    "11:38:42", "11:38:43", "11:38:44", "11:38:45", "11:38:46", 
    "11:38:47", "11:38:48", "11:38:50", "11:38:51", "11:38:52", 
    "11:38:53", "11:38:54", "11:38:55", "11:38:56", "11:38:57", 
    "11:38:58", "11:38:59", "11:39:00", "11:39:02", "11:39:03", 
    "11:39:04", "11:39:05", "11:39:06", "11:39:07", "11:39:09", 
    "11:39:10", "11:39:11", "11:39:12", "11:39:13", "11:39:14", 
    "11:39:15", "11:39:16", "11:39:17", "11:39:18", "11:39:20", 
    "11:39:21", "11:39:22", "11:39:23", "11:39:24", "11:39:25", 
    "11:39:26", "11:39:28", "11:39:29", "11:39:30", "11:39:31", 
    "11:39:32", "11:39:33", "11:39:34", "11:39:35", "11:39:36", 
    "11:39:37", "11:39:38", "11:39:39", "11:39:40", "11:39:42", 
    "11:39:43", "11:39:44", "11:39:45", "11:39:47", "11:39:48", 
    "11:39:49", "11:39:50", "11:39:52", "11:39:55", "11:39:59", 
    "11:40:01", "11:40:02", "11:40:04", "11:40:05", "11:40:06", 
    "11:40:07", "11:40:08", "11:40:15", "11:40:17", "11:40:18", 
    "11:40:19", "11:40:20", "11:40:21", "11:40:23", "11:40:24", 
    "11:40:25", "11:40:26", "11:40:28", "11:40:29", "11:40:30", 
    "11:40:31", "11:40:32", "11:40:33", "11:40:34", "11:40:35", 
    "11:40:37", "11:40:39", "11:40:41", "11:40:44", "11:40:45", 
    "11:40:48", "11:40:53", "11:41:09", "11:41:10", "11:41:12", 
    "11:41:13", "11:41:14", "11:43:01", "11:43:02", "11:43:03", 
    "11:43:12", "11:43:13", "11:43:14", "11:43:16", "11:43:17", 
    "11:43:18", "11:43:19", "11:43:20", "11:43:23", "11:43:25", 
    "11:43:27", "11:43:33", "11:43:39", "11:43:50", "11:43:51", 
    "11:43:52", "11:44:01", "11:44:03", "12:05:42", "12:05:44", 
    "12:05:46", "12:05:56", "12:05:58", "12:06:00", "12:06:01", 
    "12:06:02", "12:06:04", "12:06:07", "12:06:08", "12:06:10", 
    "12:06:13", "12:06:24", "12:06:25", "12:06:26", "12:06:28", 
    "12:06:29", "12:06:30", "12:06:32", "12:06:35", "12:06:38", 
    "12:06:39", "12:06:40", "12:06:42", "12:06:43", "12:06:44", 
    "12:06:45", "12:06:47", "12:06:53", "12:06:54", "12:06:55", 
    "12:06:56", "12:06:57", "12:07:06", "12:07:07", "12:07:08", 
    "12:07:10", "12:07:12", "12:07:14", "12:07:15", "12:07:18", 
    "12:07:20", "12:07:27", "12:07:29", "12:07:30", "12:07:31", 
    "12:07:33", "12:07:34", "12:07:35", "12:07:36", "12:07:38", 
    "12:07:39", "12:07:40", "12:07:42", "12:07:43", "12:07:44", 
    "12:07:46", "12:07:47", "12:07:48", "12:07:49", "12:07:50", 
    "12:07:51", "12:07:53", "12:07:54", "12:07:55", "12:07:56", 
    "12:07:57", "12:07:58", "12:07:59", "12:08:00", "12:08:01", 
    "12:08:02", "12:08:03", "12:08:05", "12:08:06", "12:08:07", 
    "12:08:08", "12:08:10", "12:08:11", "12:08:12", "12:08:13", 
    "12:08:14", "12:08:15", "12:08:16", "12:08:17", "12:08:18", 
    "12:08:19", "12:08:21", "12:08:22", "12:08:23", "12:08:24", 
    "12:08:25", "12:08:26", "12:08:27", "12:08:28", "12:08:29", 
    "12:08:30", "12:08:31", "12:08:33", "12:08:34", "12:08:35", 
    "12:08:36", "12:08:37", "12:08:38", "12:08:39", "12:08:40", 
    "12:08:41", "12:08:43", "12:08:44", "12:08:45", "12:08:46", 
    "12:08:47", "12:08:48", "12:08:49", "12:08:50", "12:08:51", 
    "12:08:52", "12:08:54", "12:08:55", "12:08:56", "12:08:57", 
    "12:08:58", "12:08:59", "12:09:00", "12:09:01", "12:09:02", 
    "12:09:03", "12:09:04", "12:09:05", "12:09:07", "12:09:08", 
    "12:09:09", "12:09:10", "12:09:11", "12:09:12", "12:09:13", 
    "12:09:14", "12:09:15", "12:09:16", "12:09:18", "12:09:19", 
    "12:09:20", "12:09:21", "12:09:22", "12:09:23", "12:09:24", 
    "12:09:27", "12:09:28", "12:09:29", "12:09:31", "12:09:32", 
    "12:09:40", "12:09:41", "12:09:42", "12:09:43", "12:09:44", 
    "12:09:45", "12:09:46", "12:09:47", "12:09:49", "12:10:04", 
    "12:10:05", "12:10:06", "12:10:07", "12:10:09", "12:10:10", 
    "12:10:14", "12:10:15", "12:10:16", "12:10:18", "12:10:19", 
    "12:10:20", "12:10:21", "12:10:22", "12:10:23", "12:10:24", 
    "12:10:25", "12:10:26", "12:10:28", "12:10:32", "12:10:35", 
    "12:10:37", "12:10:38", "12:10:39", "12:10:54", "12:11:09", 
    "12:11:10", "12:11:11", "12:11:12", "12:11:14", "12:11:15", 
    "12:11:18", "12:11:20", "12:11:21", "12:17:39", "12:17:40", 
    "12:17:42", "12:17:45", "12:17:50", "12:17:51", "12:17:52", 
    "12:17:53", "12:17:55", "12:17:56", "12:17:57", "12:17:59", 
    "12:18:00", "12:18:02", "12:18:09", "12:18:10", "12:18:14", 
    "12:18:15", "12:18:24", "12:18:38", "12:18:40", "12:18:41", 
    "20:39:39", "20:39:41", "20:48:52", "20:48:54", "20:48:55", 
    "20:49:01", "20:49:02", "20:49:03", "20:49:09"), class = "factor"), 
    csUriStem = c("/eacommon/systemconfigurationservice.svc/custombinding", 
    "/services/2015v1/engservice.svc/custombinding", "/eacommon/systemconfigurationservice.svc/custombinding", 
    "/eacommon/systemconfigurationservice.svc/custombinding", 
    "/services/2015v1/engservice.svc/custombinding", "/eaudit/services/sapv1/engservice.svc/custombinding"
    ), timeTaken = c(7421L, 8390L, 515L, 505L, 1385L, 1365L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
#create subset of the original data
iislog1 <- iislog %>% select(iisdate,iistime,csUriStem,timeTaken)
#Find Count by Url and then Avg,Max,Min timeTaken for each Url
iislog6 <- sqldf(SELECT csUriStem AS iislog6$baseUrl FROM iislog1,
                 Count(*) as iislog6$totalRequests,
                 AVG(timeTaken) AS iislog6$avgRequestDuration,
                 MAX(timeTaken) AS iislog6$maxRequestDuration,
                 MIN(timeTaken) AS iislog6$minRequestDuration
                 GROUP BY iislog6$baseUrl
                 ORDER By iislog6$totalRequests DESC
)
```

Comment: paste the output of dput(head(islog1) into your  question to provide easy to use data to work with.

Comment: for some reason, it's mostly timestamps from column iistime.

Comment: The other option is using dplyr, ```#Find unique URLs by grouping.
iislog2 <- iislog1 %>% group_by(csUriStem) %>% summarise(count=n())``` I just need to add the Avg,Max,Min from the timeTaken column.

Comment: iislog2 <- iislog1 %>% group_by(csUriStem) %>% summarise(count=n(), Avg = mean(timeTaken), Max = max(timeTaken), Min = min(TimeTaken))

Comment: Don't think that is working. The AVG column is all the same answer 810.3536. The Max column is also the same answer of 77013, and the min column is Inf. ```
  csUriStem                                        count   Avg   Max   Min
  <chr>                                            <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 /api/common/getallactiveengagements/clara           29  810.3536 77013   Inf
``` I think the issue is that those commands are getting the Avg, Max, Min for the whole data set. I need them per Url or per csUriStem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do. I mainly used your SQL to translate it into R.

group_by is very powerfull in R and it is easy in use.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

iislog1 <- iislog %>% select(iisdate,iistime,csUriStem,timeTaken)
iislog6 <- group_by(iislog1, csUriStem) %>% summarise(totalRequests = n(),
avgRequestDuration = mean(timeTaken), maxRequestDuration = max(timeTaken),
minRequestDuration = min(timeTaken))

# order by
iislog6 <- arrange(iislog6, totalRequests)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's interesting because I can't say for sure if this is really working. The data near the tail of the set looks accurate, but the data at the head looks inaccurate because the Avg, Max, Min columns all have the same numbers.

Comment: I looked at this again and it is surely correct. Thanks for the help. I'm learning....

Comment: You can order by desc by doing this:
 `iislog6 <- arrange(iislog6, desc(totalRequests))`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the dput output in the question so we used the data in the Note at the end.

The SQL syntax in the code in the question was incorrect -- it was a mix of SQL and R but the string must be pure SQL like this:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("SELECT 
    csUriStem AS baseUrl,
    COUNT(*) AS totalRequests,
    AVG(timeTaken) AS avgRequestDuration,
    MAX(timeTaken) AS maxRequestDuration,
    MIN(timeTaken) AS minRequestDuration
  FROM iislog1
  GROUP BY baseUrl
  ORDER BY totalRequests DESC")
```

### Note

This is the data used in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "iisdate  iistime                                              csUriStem timeTaken
1 2019-05-17 03:05:39 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding      7421
2 2019-05-17 03:07:22          /Services/2015V1/EngService.svc/customBinding      8390
3 2019-05-17 03:16:40 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding       515
4 2019-05-17 03:17:39 /eACommon/SystemConfigurationService.svc/customBinding       505
5 2019-05-17 03:25:22          /Services/2015V1/EngService.svc/customBinding      1385
6 2019-05-17 03:31:16    /eAudIT/Services/SAPv1/EngService.svc/customBinding      1365"
iislog1 <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Good to see how I can use sqldf too in this case.